# How to delete the duplicates and keep the first row only when these rows are next to each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Question

- How to drop rows with repeated values in a certain column and keep the first, only when they are next to each other?
- The pandas method `pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates` is not an answer, as it drops all the duplicated rows, even when they are not next to each other.

### Code Example

```py
import pandas as pd

example_df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['John','Mery','Sarah','Jay','Lala','Mike'], 
                           'Day':['Monday','Monday','Tuesday','Tuesday','Monday','Tuesday']})

example_df
>>>    Name      Day
0      John     Monday
1      Mery     Monday
2      Sarah    Tuesday
3      Jay      Tuesday
4      Lala     Monday
5      Mike     Tuesday
```

- My desired output is shown as follows, with the variable `desired_df`

```py
desired_df
>>>    Name      Day
0      John     Monday
1      Sarah    Tuesday
2      Lala     Monday
3      Mike     Tuesday
```

- As you can see above, only duplicates that are next to each other are deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use shift and then compare with the original column. Wherever the values are not equal, that means it is not a consecutive duplicate and that can be retained

```
example_df[example_df['Day'].shift(1) != example_df['Day']]

    name    Day
0   John    Monday
2   Sarah   Tuesday
4   Lala    Monday
5   Mike    Tuesday
```

example_df along with shifted day:

```
example_df['Day_1_shifted'] = example_df['Day'].shift(1)

    name    Day     Day_1_shifted
0   John    Monday  NaN
1   Mery    Monday  Monday
2   Sarah   Tuesday Monday
3   Jay     Tuesday Tuesday
4   Lala    Monday  Tuesday
5   Mike    Tuesday Monday
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my ugly, slow solution that also works : )

```
temp = example_df.copy()

for index, row in example_df.iterrows():
    if index == len(example_df.index) -1:
        break
    if example_df.loc[index,'Day'] == example_df.loc[index+1,'Day']:
        temp.drop(index+1,inplace=True)

example_df = temp
```

Comment: it would be much faster not to use `for loop` if the dataframe gets huge...so I chose the answer of @ggaurav . Thank you

Comment: will the other solution work if there are three duplicates in a row however? I believe mine still works in that instance, maybe the other one works as well there too

Comment: Yes, the other solution works with N rows of duplicates as well.